# PHP file won't work in root folder of website

Tags: php, wordpress, root

My PHP file won't work in root folder of website.  If it's in another folder, called whatever, it works. But it won't work in the root folder. It's a blank white page.

It's a simple contact form (contact.html) with a `contact.php` file to process the form.  I always keep them together in the same folder. It won't work in root.

Contact.php file:

```
    <?php
    $subject = $_POST['sub'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $from = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['msg'];
    $to = "stackoverflow@gmail.com";
    $send_email = mail($to,$subject,$message);
     if($send_email){
     echo "Your message is successfully sent!!!";
    }
    else{
     echo "Error in sending contact email!!!";
    }
    ?>
```

Added contact.html by request:

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <table>
    <form name="contact_form" method="post" action="contact.php">
    <tr>
    <td><b>PHP Contact Form</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Subject</td>
    <td><input name="sub" id="sub" type="text" size="75"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td><input name="name" id="name" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><input name="email" id="email" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Message</td>
    <td><textarea name="msg" cols="60" rows="5" id="msg"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
    </tr>
    </form>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

.htaccess file

```
    # Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php

    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress

    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Adaptive-Images ------------------------------------------------------------------        -----------------

    # Add any directories you wish to omit from the Adaptive-Images process on a new         line, as follows:
    # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !some-directory
    # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !another-directory

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !assets

    # Send any GIF, JPG, or PNG request that IS NOT stored inside one of the above directories
    # to adaptive-images.php so we can select appropriately sized versions

    RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ adaptive-images.php

    # END Adaptive-Images -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
            </IfModule>

            # END WordPress
```

Comment: So the code works find in one place but not the other. So one can conclude that the problem is not with the code (i.e. pointless to post it) but with the configuration of your web server. `htaccess` etc perhaps?

Comment: Can you put your html code as well pls ?

Comment: can you show your `<form` tag from the `html` file

Comment: No **headers** *equals* **FAIL**, *totally*.

Comment: *stackoverflow@gmail.com*, oh good "plug".

Comment: I quote: *"Won't work in root"*. - Won't work **period**. Man, do your *homework.*

Comment: @Fred No one is __perfect__ give him some time to understand what stack is for..too many comments for a novice

Comment: @swapnesh I see this too often. Some including myself end up fixing it "the way it should be", only to be downvoted by (potentially) the OP, because it doesn't "work". (It doesn't work.....with a big question mark). So, there's a lot of information out there for people to spend the time to figure out the "why". It's a classic case of "Fool me once, shame on you. Fool me twice, shame on ME."

Comment: @Fred lol ....well said :)

Comment: Ok... the **plot thickens**. I don't **$_GET** the "edit". Can anyone make **heads or tails** out of this? It works but it doesn't work. *Giving my head a shake*. (baffled).

Comment: Oooohhhhhhhhh... this is **Wordpress** related. Aaahhh, I get it now!!! Well, I for one cannot help you, *sorry son*. @swapnesh => You're a Wordpress guy (from what I've gathered), can you figure this one out? His `.htaccess` has a reference to Wordpress in it.

Comment: Add this as first string in your php `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set("display_errors", 1); `, does it give any error?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably making mistake at the `action` if the formn.try to give the complete URL to acces the file.

**1.Make a page name contact and place action like this:**

```
   <form name="contact_form" method="post" action="/contact">
```

it will redirect you to the contact page by grabbing its slug.

OR

**2.You can set a bloginfo URL:**

```
   <form name="contact_form" method="post" action="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/contact.php">
```

Note:**Dont forget to initalize**`global $wpdb;` and `global $post;`

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and solved only when i moved contact.php in another folder than root , ex: contact/contact.php and remaked the link  
bye